# A children's novel featuring a race of spider-like aliens

Tags: story-identification, aliens, childrens-novel

Some 30 years ago when I was in the 6th grade, I remember reading an excerpt from a sci-fi novel in my English class.

I don’t remember much of the story, but it did feature a race of intelligent spider-like aliens. I remember that the protagonist was a young human boy who played some instrument (I think it was a flute or something) and he befriends one of the spider-like aliens. Also, I’m fairly certain that there was the word water in the title (Sweet Water? Clear Water?).

It’s been about 30 years, so I don’t remember much else. This has been bothering me for years. Does anyone know what this book is?

Comment: Water is a pretty common word in titles; https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/adv_search_results.cgi?USE_1=title_title&O_1=contains&TERM_1=water&C=AND&USE_2=title_ttype&O_2=exact&TERM_2=NOVEL&USE_3=title_title&O_3=exact&TERM_3=&USE_4=title_title&O_4=exact&TERM_4=&USE_5=title_title&O_5=exact&TERM_5=&USE_6=title_title&O_6=exact&TERM_6=&USE_7=title_title&O_7=exact&TERM_7=&USE_8=title_title&O_8=exact&TERM_8=&USE_9=title_title&O_9=exact&TERM_9=&USE_10=title_title&O_10=exact&TERM_10=&ORDERBY=title_title&ACTION=query&START=0&TYPE=Title

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think this is probably [Sweetwater](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/504200.Sweetwater) by Laurence Yep. It was published in 1973 so it's old enough for you to have read it 30 years ago.

[image: Sweetwater]

> On the planet Harmony, Tyree and his people are fighting to survive. Their beautiful world holds terrible dangers -- vicious sea creatures, diminishing food supplies, and, at the heart of it all, a rising tide that will soon destroy the city where they cling to their way of life. Tyree has secretly befriended Amadeus, the greatest songmaster of the native alien race. Amadeus teaches Tyree about the power of music, and, to Tyree's blind sister, he gives an awesome treasure. But his gift kindles the fears of Tyree's people -- fears more dangerous than the sea itself. Tyree must help his people before they tear their community apart.

I cannot find a copy of this book, but there is a copy [on Google books here](https://www.google.co.uk/books/edition/Sweetwater/CHEZcA1GafgC) that allows limited searching. Using the search I find that Tyree is given a flute, and the aliens (the *Argan*) are described as four foot high spiders. Given these clues and the name of the book it seems very likely this is the book you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, that’s it! Solved! Thank you.